# Cannot implicitly cast to IEnumerable<T>... but I can the other way... why?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, repository-pattern

I'm learning about the Repository Pattern so I can apply it to WPF MVVM. I got this piece of code from another post on SO...

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
}
```

So I tried to make it work for me in the following manner...

```
class CustomersRepository : IRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Models.Customer> GetAll<T>()
    {
        DataView results;

        // some DAL retrieval code

        foreach (DataRowView row in results)
        {
            yield return new Models.Customer(row["Label"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And by calling the method from my Model...

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> ReadCustomers()
{
    IRepository repository = new CustomersRepository();
    return repository.GetAll<Models.Customer>();
}
```

But I get an error, **"CustomersRepository does not implement interface member "IRepository.GetAll< T >()". "CustomersRepository.GetAll< T >()" cannot implement "IRepository.GetAll< T >()" because it does not have the matching return type of "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< T >"**.

---

However, if I define the type argument in the interface's identifier instead, and I remove the type argument from the method call...

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

...and I adjust the implementation, and the call from my Model accordingly...

```
class CustomersRepository : IRepository<Models.Customer>
{
    public IEnumerable<Models.Customer> GetAll()
    {
        // same body content
    }
}
```

...

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> ReadCustomers()
{
    IRepository<Models.Customer> repository = new CustomersRepository();
    return repository.GetAll();
}
```

...then it works perfectly!

My questions are:

1. Why can't it implicitly cast the yield return in my original attempt? Is this by design, or am I misinterpreting how type arguments work?
2. Considering that I want to loose-couple the CustomersRepository to my Customer model, and considering that the Model represents a single data entity, is there a better way than using a static factory method in my Customer model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of IRepository doesn't cover all possibilities the interface can ask for. The interface specifies that you have a method `GetAll` with a generic type parameter which in turn returns a IEnumerable of the same type.

By implementing this interface with `public IEnumerable<Models.Customer> GetAll<T>()`, no matter what is the type parameter, you'll always be returning a `IEnumerable<Models.Customer>`, which doesn't correspond to the interface signature.

I think you should go on with your second implementation, unless a `CustomersRepository` is able to return anything other than `IEnumerable<Models.Customer>`

If that's the case, you can do this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Models.Customer)))
    {
        DataView results;
        // some DAL retrieval code

        foreach (DataRowView row in results)
        {
            yield return (T) new Models.Customer(row["Label"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in this, just to make sure I understand, your converting an object of new Models.Customer to which ever Type has been passed through by declaring (T) before you return it?

Comment: @Derek, in this case, I'm checking before to be sure that `T` is of type `Models.Customer`. I just have to cast it to T before returning because otherwise the compiler will tell me it can't convert Models.Customer to T implicitly.